# Howto copy user profile?

Tags: windows-8.1

In Windows 7 I was able to copy user profiles by renaming the C:\User\userprofile folder to "Default" and then copy the temporary "Default" profile to any other existing profile in System -> User Profiles.

This is still possible in Windows 8.1 but when login to the new profile, the apps won't work anymore. If you want to start an app it just crashes and lands back on the start menu.

Has anyone figured out how to copy a profile in Win 8.1? I google'd and this is my last place to find an answer.

For your information: I'm using Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit

Comment: Have you tried logging in as a different user, copying the profile you want to another folder, then renaming Default, renaming the copied folder to Default, and then creating the new user?

Comment: Try this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781200(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Davidenko: A link to a 100+ page PDF for Windows Server 2003 hardly seems appropriate here.  Perhaps the content changed underneath your url?